# Why can't this expression be factorised without using trigonometrical identities?

Tags: calculus, derivatives, implicit-differentiation

The question specified

Find $\frac{dy}{dx}$ of $\tan^{-1}(\frac{3x - x^3}{1 - 3x^2})$

However, we were asked to try the sum without using the trig identities of $\tan(3x)$. I used chain rule and the general formula of $\frac{d}{dx}\tan^{-1}(x) = \frac{1}{1 + x^2}$ and after few steps I get the expression $\frac{6x^2 + 3x^4 + 3}{3x^4 + 3x^2 + x^6 + 1}$ and this is where I cannot further simplify. Can someone please point out how to proceed or is the only way to do this sum using the trig identities ?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From the [binomial theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Binomial_theorem) we know
\begin{align}
(a+b)^2 &= a^2 + 2ab +b^2\\
(a+b)^3 &= a^3 + 3a^2b + 3ab^2 + b^3
\end{align}
Now notice that
\begin{align}
\frac{6x^2 + 3x^4 + 3}{3x^4 + 3x^2 + x^6 + 1} & = 3\frac{ x^4 +2x^2  + 1}{ x^6 +3x^4 + 3x^2  + 1}\\
& = 3\frac{ (x^2)^2 +2(x^2)(1)  + 1^2}{ (x^2)^3 +3(x^2)^2(1) + 3(x^2)(1)^2  + 1^3}
\end{align}
Can you conclude the problem from here?

Comment: Thanks a ton! And yes I can proceed

Answer (score 0):

One can also avoid requiring trigonometric identities, other than the basic definitions, in this way.  Writing the equation to be differentiated implicitly as $ \ \tan y \ = \  \frac{x^3 - 3x}{3x^2 - 1} \ \ , \ $ use this to describe a right triangle with "legs"  $ \  u \ = \ x^3 - 3x \ $ and $ \ 3x^2 - 1 \ = \ u' + 2 \ \ . $  The hypotenuse of this conceptual triangle is given by $$ H^2 \ \ = \ \ (x^3 \ - \ 3x)^2 \ + \ (3x^2 \ - \ 1)^2 \ \ = \ \ (x^6 \ - \ 6x^4 \ + \ 9x^2) \ + \ (9x^4 \ - \ 6x^2 \ + \ 1) $$ $$ = \ \  x^6 \ + \ 3x^4 \ + \ 3x^2  \  + \ 1 \ \ = \ \ (x^2 \ + \ 1)^3 \ \ , $$
as **Robert Lee** shows.  We then re-arrange the equation as
$$ \tan y \ = \  \frac{u}{u' \ + \ 2} \ \ \Rightarrow \ \ (u' \ +  \ 2) · \tan y \ \ = \ \ u $$
$$  \Rightarrow \ \ (u' \ +  \ 2)' · \tan y \ \ + \ \ (u' \ +  \ 2) · (\tan y)' \ \ = \ \ u' $$ $$ \Rightarrow \ \  u'' · \tan y \ \ + \ \ (u' \ +  \ 2)  · (\sec^2 y) \ y' \ \ = \ \ u' $$
$$ y' \ \ = \ \ \frac{u' \ - \ u'' ·  \tan y }{(u' \ +  \ 2)  · \sec^2 y} \ \ = \ \ \frac{u' \ - \ u'' ·  \left(\frac{u}{u' \ + \ 2} \right)}{u' \ +  \ 2  } \ ·  \ (\cos^2 y) $$ $$ = \ \ \frac{u' · (u' \ +  \ 2) \ - \ u'' ·  u}{(u' \ +  \ 2)^2  } \ ·  \ \left[\frac{ (u' \ +  \ 2) }{H } \right]^2 \ \ = \ \ \frac{(3x^2 \ - \ 3) · (3x^2 \ - \ 1) \ - \ 6x ·  (x^3 - 3x)}{H^2  }  $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{3·(3x^4 \ - \ 3x^2 \ - \ x^2 \ + \ 1  \ - \ 2x^4 \ + \  6x^2)}{H^2  } \ \ = \  \ \frac{3·(x^4 \ + \ 2x^2  \ + \ 1  )}{H^2  } $$
$$ = \ \ \frac{3·(x^2 \ + \ 1)^2}{(x^2 \ + \ 1)^3 } \ \ = \  \ \frac{3}{x^2 \ + \ 1 } \ \ , $$
again employing the binomial theorem.  (This approach was taken to postpone  manipulation of polynomials as late as manageable.  You probably cannot evade dealing with the rational function you obtained:  the problem seems to be constructed to produce it.)

Comment: Yeah. Thanks for the help.